# Spring framework not decoding path variables with semicolon

Tags: java, spring

In a Spring framework application I want to pass a URL encoded path variable value of `;,/?:@&=+$-_.!~*'()#` to the following method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{et}/{ei}/{ls}", method = RequestMethod.PATCH)
@ResponseBody
public JSONObject lk(  @PathVariable("et") String et,
                   @PathVariable("ei") String ei,
                   @PathVariable("ls") LS ls,
                   HttpServletRequest request,
                   HttpServletResponse response)
        throws UIServerException {
```

When I test it using the following curl command:

```
curl -s -X PATCH "http://example.com/etxx/%3B%2C%2F%3F%3A%40%26%3D%2B%24-_.%21~%2A%27%28%29%23/lsxx"
```

I can see that the path variable has not been decoded correctly in the debugger - the semicolon and colon from the encoded string are removed.

I've tried setting the following but with no luck:

```
final UrlPathHelper urlPathHelper = new UrlPathHelper();
urlPathHelper.setRemoveSemicolonContent(false);
configurer.setUrlPathHelper(urlPathHelper);
```

Comment: It looks like the HttpServletRequestpassed to org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleMatch has already decoded the URI encoded string before applying the path matchers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public HttpFirewall allowUrlEncodedSlashHttpFirewall() {
        final DefaultHttpFirewall firewall = new DefaultHttpFirewall();
        firewall.setAllowUrlEncodedSlash(true);
        return firewall;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.httpFirewall(allowUrlEncodedSlashHttpFirewall());
    }
}

 public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        final RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping = super.requestMappingHandlerMapping();
        requestMappingHandlerMapping.setUrlDecode(false);
        return requestMappingHandlerMapping;
    }
}
```

- add security setting to allow encoded forward slashes
- disable URL decoding in request mapping
- (also had to fix in Nginx reverse proxy)

Answer (score 0):

Although not very sure but this is just a possibility. Can you try setting `setRemoveSemicolonContent(false)` at the  `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` level and check if it works

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration {

    @Override
    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {

        final RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping = super.requestMappingHandlerMapping();
        requestMappingHandlerMapping.setRemoveSemicolonContent(false);

        return requestMappingHandlerMapping;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I tried this variant as well as the one in the original question and neither worked. I see the following error: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/etxx/;,/%3F:@&=+$-_.!~*'()%23/lsxx

Comment: /etxx / ;, / %3F:@&=+$-_.!~*'()%23 / lsxx >> /1/2/3/4for this example you might need 4 path variables; Also I noticed you have a class type LS